# Apigee query by Name using Contains does not work

Tags: apigee

The Apigee documentation gives the following example:

```
/restaurants?ql=select * where name contains 'diner' order by name asc
```

But when I try to query my Collection "Articles" using the "contains" comparison for the attribute "name" I get an error. I can query using Contains any attribute other then "name". Even using the portal it gives me the following error message:

```
error getting articles: Entity 'article' with property named 'name' is not full text indexed. You cannot use the 'contains' operand on this field
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the name field strictly for the name of the restaurant and add another field called "diner" that you can set to yes or no.  Name is handled specially in Usergrid/App Services.

Comment: I was using a "title" attribute on my entity, but as the Name attribute also shows on te portal, o thought it would be better.
Just don't understand how they have a "contains" query using "name" attribute in the documentation example if it is not possible to do so.

Comment: You can use a query like "name = 'Joes Diner'", but cannot use a query where "name contains 'Diner'".  The name field is not full text indexed.  Therefore, you need a second field that designates whether of not the restaurant is a diner.